# How to parameterize a duration?

Tags: ros, roscpp, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have used the following pattern a number of times, across a variety of packages:

```
double my_param_seconds;
ros::param::get("~my_param", my_param_seconds);
my_param_ = ros::Duration(my_param_seconds);
```

This seems awkward compared to parameterizing integers or doubles. It's fine if it's only one or two, but for a safety state machine which has a half-dozen parameterized timeouts, this is a drag. I can write my own little wrapper function, but perhaps something standard already exists?

Alternatively, is it better to simply store the seconds value, and convert that to a `ros::Duration` at the point of use?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104426/how-to-parameterize-a-duration?/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2013-11-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-11-24**:
Can you define "awkward" in this context? I am not sure to understand what you would like to see improved here... Having the possibility to directly retrieve a ros::Duration object from the parameter API?

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-11-24**:
Sure, have attempted to clarify the question. I know that parameter types are constrained by the XMLRPC types, but I'm wondering if a general Time/Duration helper already exists before I roll my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately there is not such as direct conversion. However this sounds like a nice improvement.

The `get` function is defined in [rosparam.h](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/hydro-devel/clients/roscpp/include/ros/param.h).

If you add the missing overloading:

```
ROSCPP_DECL bool get(const std::string& key, ros::Duration& s);
```

...the templated get will automagically use it. This should even work if you define this function in your own C++ source file (considering you keep the same namespace). Hence, you can fork the project on GitHub, submit a pull request providing the additional getter. In the meanwhile (i.e. until a new version of roscomm is released), you can check the ROS version and provide the overloading yourself for older ROS versions.

As ROS relies on Boost.DateTime to store time-related values, I suggest you use the Boost.DateTime API in the get function to ensure a consistent parsing.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0